# spring-boot-devtools - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: spring-boot

I have just added the [spring-boot-devtools](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/17/devtools-in-spring-boot-1-3) dependency to our working spring-boot projects and am getting the following error when I start the tomcat server via STS.

It appears that the memory is getting filled up somehow but I am not sure how. When the application start it halts for about a minute and then throws the exception.

Any ideas of how to solve this?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'classPathFileSystemWatcher' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$RestartConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.mycompany.useradmin.Application.main(Application.java:43) [bin/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.resolve(UnixFileSystem.java:108) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:262) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:1212) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FolderSnapshot.collectFiles(FolderSnapshot.java:64) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FolderSnapshot.collectFiles(FolderSnapshot.java:68) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FolderSnapshot.collectFiles(FolderSnapshot.java:68) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FolderSnapshot.collectFiles(FolderSnapshot.java:68) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FolderSnapshot.collectFiles(FolderSnapshot.java:68) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FolderSnapshot.collectFiles(FolderSnapshot.java:68) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FolderSnapshot.collectFiles(FolderSnapshot.java:68) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FolderSnapshot.collectFiles(FolderSnapshot.java:68) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FolderSnapshot.<init>(FolderSnapshot.java:59) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FileSystemWatcher.saveInitialSnapshots(FileSystemWatcher.java:168) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FileSystemWatcher.start(FileSystemWatcher.java:139) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.classpath.ClassPathFileSystemWatcher.afterPropertiesSet(ClassPathFileSystemWatcher.java:90) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
```

Comment: What's your java version? And VM settings?

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_65".  Not entirely sure how to get the VM settings you want.  Do you mean STS (eclispe) or the settings in the running tomcat server?

Comment: Here is my STS.ini.  -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xverify:none
-Xmx2048m
-javaagent:/opt/sts-bundle-3.7.1/sts-3.7.1.RELEASE/lombok.jar